# A C library for finding local maxima?

Tags: c, numerical

I'm trying to write an audio analysis application, and I need to identify local maxima in a 2D array which represents a spectrogram. I've already got an open source library that can generate the spectrogram using Fast Fourier Transforms, but I was wondering if anybody knew of any good libraries to help me with actually finding the maxima? I'm not quite sure what to search Google for - the best I could think of was "numerical library" but that hasn't got me very far.

Preferably in C, but I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peak finding is a fairly general problem. It has already been discussed once on SO as [Peak detection of measured signal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260/peak-detection-of-measured-signal).

The answers provided include several viable heuristics.

Of course, I prefer [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260/peak-detection-of-measured-signal#24259) if you need rigor, but ROOT is written in c++, and is almost certainly too heavy for your application, so you'll need to strip out just the code you want...

Answer (score 1):

The GNU Scientific Library features a [multidimensional minimization framework](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Multidimensional-Minimization.html) that can be made to work for maximization easily enough. It's designed to only return a single minimum rather than a bunch of different minima, however.