# Audio analyzer for finding songs pitch

Tags: java, c++, iphone

Is there anyway to analyze the audio pitches programmatically. For example, i know most of the players show a graph or bar & if the songs pitch is high @ time t, the bar goes up at time t .. something like this. Is there any utility/tool/API to determine songs pitch so that we interpolate that to a bar which goes up & down.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naive but robust: transform a modest length segment into [Fourier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) space and [find the peaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260/peak-detection-of-measured-signal). Repeat as necessary.

Speed may be an issue, so choose the segment length as a power of 2 so that you can use the [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) which is, well, *fast*.

Lots of related stuff on SO already. Try: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Fourier+transform

Answer (score 2):

Well, unfortunately I'm not really an expert on audio with the iPhone, but I can point you towards a couple good resources.

Core Audio is probably going to be a big thing in what you want to do: htp://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html

As well, the Audio Toolbox may be of some help: htp://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/Frameworks/Media/AudioToolbox/index.html

If you are have a developer account, there are plenty of people on the forums that can help you: htps://devforums.apple.com/community/iphone

You'll have to add in a 't' in the http portion of those URLs, as I cannot post more than one hyperlink (sorry!).

Answer (score 1):

To find the current pitch of a song, you need to learn about the Discrete Time Fourier Transform. To find the tempo, you need autocorrelation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may be speaking of is a graphic equalizer, which displays the amplitude of different frequency ranges at a given time in an audio signal.  It normally equipped with controls to modify the amplitudes between the given frequency ranges.  Here's an [example](http://graphic-equalizer-studio-2005.smartcode.com/images/sshots/graphic_equalizer_studio_2005_2718.gif).  Is that sort of what you're thinking of?

EDIT: Also, your numerous tags don't really give any indication of what language you might be using here, so I can't really suggest any specific techniques or libraries.