# C++: Accumulator matrix (3D arrays)

Tags: c++, opencv, boost

I am trying to do some hough voting in 3D space in which I will have an accumulator over 3 dimensions which can be thought of as a 3D array. I will then want to search for peaks in this array.

I was wondering if `boost`, `opencv` or even the `std lib` have an inbuilt structure for this which can give fast search times when looking for local maxima?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is any function like this in the libraries you mentionned. You could eventually look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260/peak-detection-of-measured-signal

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Boost.Accumulators](http://boost.org/libs/accumulators) library?