# Peak detection in accelerometer data

Tags: java, android, algorithm, detection

I am trying to detect peaks in the accelerometer data so I can find the number of steps. The speed I have it polling on it is game. I think that should be a good speed to give me data but not to give me too many data points. Are there any algorithms you recommend to figure out the peak? I currently have the data in and excel and I tried graphing it out but there are way too many little jumps up and down.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260/peak-detection-of-measured-signal?

Comment: I've looked into that. I am not sure which of those algs I could use for this. Since I am looking for step detection I think it has to be within a certain range. I know what range the data should be for a step.

Answer (score 0):

I once used peak detection algorithm for some computer vision application. There are many sophisticated techniques, but I wrote very raw approach myself:

I used `windowed averaging` filter which smoothed all the local ups and downs (if your peak is narrow used smaller window size).

Then I took `discrete derivative` and find all points where derivative sign-ess changed from `+ve` to `-ve`. Then finally I took average of values around all those points and applied `threshold` around `1/3 of average`.

It's not best approach but worked out for me well. You can play around with different discrete filters either in `matlab` or `python`. There is a very good plugin in `python` called `scipy` it can make ur life easy.