# how to detect emission lines in an optical spectra?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there any handy module to detect emission lines in a spectrum like one we get from sdss?

You can see there are many emission lines like Ha,OI in the spectrum below. In fact the spectrum is a two column data set, wavelength and flux. It is a combination of lots of scatter points. The typical interval between two points nearyby is 1.5 angstroms. I need to find all the Gaussian bumps and their line centers.

So,first I need to find the the bumps and then I need to fit them to get their centers.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260/peak-detection-of-measured-signal looks like the same question.  I've done a fair bit of this kind of work and the best approach is often dependent on your data.  Generally, the answer will involve some combination of smoothing, find local maxima, and curve fitting (if you need widths).

Comment: Did you look in the python imaging library?

Comment: I don't know what the detection of emission lines entails.  If you outline the steps more concrete advice could be given, but numpy/scipy should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I have updated my post.First find a local maximum and then fit it with a Gaussian profile. This method is too easy to believe. Anything else I miss?

Answer (score 0):

My answer comes a little bit late, but it is now that I have found myself in the same situation.

I think that the tool that best matches our needs is `Specutils`, an `Astropy` package for spectroscopy. Specifically, you may need to use either `find_lines_threshold` or `find_lines_derivative` methods from that package: https://specutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fitting.html#line-finding

According to the documentation, providing a 1D spectrum and a threshold (to filter the actual lines from the noise) the method will return a table of emission and absorption lines, identifying the central wavelengths of each of them.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. You have used Specutils? It seems we need to specify a noise region(SpectralRegion), but different lines may have different background.

Comment: As far as I understand, the noise is estimated as the standard deviation of a region. If you compute the noise from a region including actual strong emission/absorption lines, you will be overestimating the background noise. Therefore, my advise for defining a noise threshold representative of the whole spectrum would be to compute the standard deviation from as many regions free of strong lines as possible. E.g. for galaxies 4 reasonably flat ranges [(Dobos et. al 2012)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012MNRAS.420.1217D/abstract) are: 4200-4300, 4600-4800, 5400-5500 and 5600–5800 A.

Comment: @JTM Do you have another suggestion besides astropy? I work with mineral spectra, and astropy identifies the emission zones but not the absorption. I've been trying to get help from the developers but no luck...

Comment: @AngelaR.  I don't know any software specific for treating mineral spectra. Actually the same functions from `specutils` should detect absorption lines as well. In practice, unlike galaxy spectra, stellar spectra are full of absorption lines. You can find an example with a spectrum showing an absorption line [here](https://specutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fitting.html#line-finding).